# run a .exe file with argument from unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process

I want to run a .exe file with argument from unity using C#, I saw a lot of tutorials and I tried a lot of instructions and this is what I came up with so far:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "C://PATH//ABC.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "ARGUMENT";
```

The argument should create a text file, but nothing is happening, and there is no error. Can anyone tell me why is the text file not creating.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't start the process. You need to set the `StartInfo` of the process, and then start the process.

```
// Create a process
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

// Set the StartInfo of process
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C://PATH//ABC.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "ARGUMENT";

// Start the process
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Now this error is showing up when I tried them `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()`

Comment: Try without `WaitForExit()`.